# What is a Acyclic connected undirected graph?

Tags: data-structures, graph

I was going through lecture of **Minimum Spanning Tree**, It says we are supposed to find connected acyclic subgraph  graph in a Undirected graphs.

My question is that How can a connected undirected graph be a Acyclic, Since it is connected you can move to any vertex from any vertex.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: A cycle is a connected graph over `n` nodes with `n` edges; you can also think of it as a simple path for which start and end node are the same node. A tree is defined as a connected acyclic graph. The property that for any pair of nodes `a` and `b` there is a path between them is what "connected" means; a cycle requires two distinct paths between two nodes.

Answer (score 9):

It's really just a matter of definition. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory). What you seem to refer to as a cycle, is what is called a **closed walk** in the article: any path from a vertex to itself. As you have said yourself, using that definition, any connected undirected graph contains cycles. However, if you require that the subpath from the second to the last vertex be a simple path (hence **simple cycle**), i.e. one containing no repeating vertices, you end up with many connected undirected graphs which are in fact acyclic, such as trees for instance. Obviously, the path also has to contain at least 3 edges, else any `(A,B,A)` would be a cycle.

Consider the following graphs

```
     A         A
1)  / \   2)  / \
   B   C     B - C
```

only `2)` contains simple cycles, so `1)` is acyclic.

Comment: I think you misread the definition of a closed walk; it says "If repeated `vertices` are allowed". I have never seen cycles defined as containing repeated edges. That wouldn't make any sense anyway because any edge would also be a cycle.